# After importing CSV into R, the headers are not what I want

Tags: r, excel, csv

This is my CSV file (see below) with the headers "data entry", "assessor", "school name" etc, but when I import the csv file the headers become "V1", "V2", "V3" etc as shown below. what should I do so that I remain with the headers like in the csv format since its interfering with the analysis because now the headers are now seen as part of the data entered and I cant overide them manually there too many and I have too many files. Thanks.

My CSV file:

[image]

Header:

[image]

Comment: We can't say what you're doing wrong without seeing your code. Include that in your question.

Comment: I think you are missing `header = T` but you do not show the code so this is just a guess

Comment: Additionally, consider deleting the second line if it is completely empty.

Comment: @Mateusz I was using the import data set command in R studio which had set the header to FALSE, however now I have a new problem I get the following error "Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : invalid multibyte string 141"

Answer (score 1):

For R, the read module provides methods to read in tables and csvs. You can check the relevant documentation by typing:

```
help(read.csv)
```

Here is the snippet from help that tells you the signature of the method:

> read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",
>            dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...)

Note the second parameter list, *header*, has a default argument passed to it which is *TRUE*. This means that if you do not set it to *FALSE*, it will always read the header.

Because you have not shared the code, I can only guess that maybe this is your problem.

Comment: thank you all especially and @siphr. I was using the import data set command in R studio which had set the header to FALSE, however now I have a new problem I get the following error    "Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string 141"